# Fluids and density

Tags: homework-and-exercises, density, fluid-statics

Is the answer C?

Assume that you look at three objects that all float on water, but have different shapes and sizes. Which one has the greatest density?

A.The object that has the largest fraction of its volume submerged.

B.Impossible to determine in cases when the three objects have different volumes.

**C.The object that has the largest fraction of its height submerged.**

D.The object with the largest submerged height.

E.The object with the largest submerged volume.

Comment: Nope. It's answer A

Answer (score 1):

$m_{object} = \rho_{object} * V_{object}$

in equilibrium, the volume of water dislocated times the density of water should be equal to the mass of the object:

$V_{submerged} * \rho_{water} = \rho_{object} * V_{object}$

Therefore:

$\rho_{object} / \rho_{water} = V_{submerged} / V_{object} $

Thus, the higher the ratio of submerged volume, the higher the density. Answer A

Answer (score 1):

[Archimedes' Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle) says "the buoyant force on an object equals the weight of fluid displaced".

The weight of fluid displaced depends upon the volume of fluid displaced.

The volume of fluid displaced is equal to the volume of the object that is submerged.

Which is option A.